# jQuery - using global array and wait for $get to load retrieved data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, global-variables, settimeout

Been struggling all day with looking at code examples and can't get this to work.

Basically I want to load an array using the HTML from four local files.
Then I'll use that HTML to fill a div dynamically with some kind of animated slider.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the timer to wait for the html to be retrieved and assigned to the variables. The GET is working great, but the variables don't seem to be loaded outside the GET loop.

I can see the asynch GET filling the array properly, but the elements remain undefined in the loop. I think they're global variables so it shouldn't be that.

I'm new at jQuery and have been using SO for examples, so open to any suggestions - hopefully this is just an obvious fix for an experienced javascript coder.

> **Here's my code:**

```
window.standings = new Array(4);
window.iURL = 0;

standingsURL = ["MondayNight.html", "TuesdayNight.html", "WednesdayNight.html", "ThursdayNight.html"]

for (window.iURL  = 0; window.iURL  < window.standings.length; window.iURL ++) {
    $.get(standingsURL[window.iURL], function( data ) {
        window.standings[window.iURL] = data;
        alert (window.standings[window.iURL]);
      }, "text");
}

setTimeout(function repeatTimeout() {
    if(window.standings[window.standings.length] !== undefined){
        for (window.iURL  = 0; window.iURL  < window.standings.length; window.iURL ++) {
            alert (window.standings[window.iURL]);
        }
    } else {    
        alert ("Wait again");
        setTimeout(repeatTimeout, 2500);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What is this: `window.standings[window.standings.length]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I can see is that in your `repeatTimeout` function, you're referencing an item in your array that doesn't exist.

`window.standings[window.standings.length]`

which is equivalent to `window.standings[4]`

You have an array with four items in it, and you're referencing array index 4 here - but arrays are zero-indexed, so only indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3 are valid. Try:

`window.standings[window.standings.length - 1]`

Edit:

Declare an empty array:

`window.standings = []`

Instead of: `window.standings[window.iURL] = data;`, do this:

`window.standings.push(data)`

Your `if` function now checks for length:

`if(window.standings.length === 4)`

This is a relatively crude solution. Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done) for more information about the `when` function.

Comment: Okay - I'll give that a try - that looks like an simple yet obvious fix

Comment: That's better - I still get undefined for a couple of the array items when I start the loop. I thought by waiting for the last one to load all would be filled by that time. Do I have to check each item individually?

Comment: So the long answer is a bit more complicated; I'd take a look at promises in jQuery and go from there, but the shorter fix is: instead of pre-defining the length of the array, I'd declare an empty array, push new items into it and check the length. I'll edit my answer to include that solution.

Comment: That's it - I just had to adjust my $get counter from `'window.standings.length` to `standingsURL.length`. I'll check out the reference to the when function and see if It can get rid of some of the crudity. But for now - it works! Much appreciated